# How to prevent an absolutely positioned popover from clipping out of its container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function myclick() {
  let node = document.createElement("div");
  node.className = "popover";
  node.innerText = "hello world hello world";
  event.srcElement.appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.tag {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick();">apple</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick();">banana</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick();">carrot</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick();">dog</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick();">elephant</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick();">firetruck</div>
</div>
```

I've developed a complete reproduction of the issue I'm facing above. Basically, I have popovers appear from tags when you click on them. This all works perfectly, except for when the tag is near the edge of its container. In this case the tag clips out of the container. In the provided example if you click "dog" then the popover clips outside of the `container` div.

Rather, I would like the popover to move to the left as much as necessary in order to prevent itself from clipping out of the container. I've been messing with it for a while but I cannot quite figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: I would create a css class for popper (something like `.popper.right`), that sets `left: auto; right: 0` then add that class in your `myClick` function for items on the edge. But that is the tricky part, you would have to dynamically detect what is on the edge based on the width of the container and the width of each child item.

Comment: There is no way to do that with CSS only, but you'd need JS: You could get the widths of all `.tag` elements and (for each element) calculate the sum of all previous elements' widths plus their margins, and if the current `.tag` element is less than 60px wide (i.e. the width of your dropdowns), you could right-align that dropdown to the `.tag` element. But starting from the second line that becomes more complicated, since you'd have to restart calculating the overall width of the elements in each line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. I added a javascript function called `onEdge` that is suppose to detect how close a child element is to the edge. This will probably need modified for your needs (like setting how close to the parents edge you consider "too close").

```js
function onEdge(child) {
  if (child.parentElement.offsetWidth < (child.offsetLeft + child.offsetWidth))
    return true;
  return false;
}

function myclick(elm) {
  var addClass = onEdge(elm);

  let node = document.createElement("div");
  node.className = "popover" + (addClass ? " right" : "");
  node.innerText = "hello world hello world";
  event.srcElement.appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.tag {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}

.popover.right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="tag-container" class="container">
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">apple</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">banana</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">carrot</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">dog</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">elephant</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">firetruck</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh this is very nice, I especially like the `popover.right` trick. Trying it now.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having difficulty getting the `offsetLeft` since the elements in my code have to be `position: relative` so it's just giving me `7` for all of the offsetLefts.. Hmm..

Comment: hmm, interesting. In the snippet above it seems to work. Does your container also need to be `position: relaitive`? The `tag`'s already are

Comment: I do know that there is issues with left and right margins, because that will not be include in the child items `offsetWidth` value but will affect its `offsetLeft` value. But if your margins are static you should be able to figure it out (might have to add margin values to child width in the onEdge function for better accuracy)

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: You can calculate the right point of the tag and check if the popup has enough room. Add a parameter to `myclick` and pass in the element.

```
var popUpWidth = 60;
var containerWidth = 200;
function myclick(element) {
  let node = document.createElement("div");

  if(element.offsetLeft + popUpWidth > containerWidth){
     node.style.left = -20 + "px";
  }

  node.className = "popover";
  node.innerText = "hello world hello world";
  event.srcElement.appendChild(node);
}
```

Snipet:

```js
var popUpWidth = 60;
var containerWidth = 200;
function myclick(element) {
  let node = document.createElement("div");

  if(element.offsetLeft + popUpWidth > containerWidth){
     node.style.left = -20 + "px";
  }

  node.className = "popover";
  node.innerText = "hello world hello world";
  event.srcElement.appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 230px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.tag {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">apple</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">banana</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">carrot</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">dog</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">elephant</div>
  <div class="tag" onclick="myclick(this);">firetruck</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this makes the other popovers move to the left as well, which is not desired. Only when the popover clips out of its container should it move to the left (and only as far as necessary to prevent the clipping)

Comment: yeah this is like setting right:0; instead of left:0;

Comment: So you want `myclick` to be a general function for every tag, not just dog?

Comment: You can calculate if the popup has enough room. I made some edits.

Comment: Unfortunate that something like this needs to be done. Ah well, if no other answer comes along I'll accept this one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just decrement the left position slightly:

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  left: -19px;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
```

Comment: Right, I suppose this would work in this case, but I'm looking for a more general solution. The popovers in my application are much wider and need to maintain their size.

Comment: Sorry it really needs to be dynamic and not hard-coded.